# Calculation of integral

Tags: integration

I am stuck with the following calculation. What should I use? Integration by parts?
$$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} \exp \left\{ - \frac{(x_i - \mu_k)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right\} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma_P^2}} \exp \left\{ - \frac{(\mu_k - \mu_P)^2}{2 \sigma_P^2} \right\} d\mu_k \\
&= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 \cdot \sigma_P^2}} \exp \left\{ -\left(\frac{(x_i - \mu_k)^2}{2 \sigma^2} + \frac{(\mu_k - \mu_P)^2}{2 \sigma_P^2} \right) \right\}  d\mu_k \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 \cdot \sigma_P^2}} \int \exp \left\{ (-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2  \sigma_P^2) \left( (\sigma_P^2 (x_i - \mu_k)^2 + \sigma^2(\mu_k - \mu_P)^2) \right)\right\}d\mu_k \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 \cdot \sigma_P^2}} \int \frac{ \exp\left\{ (\sigma^2_P + \sigma^2) \mu_k^2 \right\} \cdot \exp\left\{ \sigma_P^2 x_i^2 + \sigma^2 \mu_P^2 \right\}  }{\exp\left\{ 2(\sigma_P^2 x_i + \sigma^2 \mu_P) \mu_k \right\}} d\mu_k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Did you try completing the square ?

Comment: are you trying to prove some property about brownian motion? it's just curiosity.


In the last line write $a(\mu_{k}+b)+c$, where $a,b,c$ dont depend on $\mu_{k}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, but I did not include it in the original question because I thought it just became messy (now included).

Comment: @Basti Actually, I am calculating (collapsed) Gibbs Sampling (Normal distribution with Normal Distribution as a conjugate prior).

Comment: See the Gaussian error function. You can use $\enspace\displaystyle\int e^{-a(x-b)^2-c(x-d)^2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+c}}e^{\frac{(ab+cd)^2}{a+c}-ab^2-cd^2}\int\limits_0^{x\sqrt{a+c}-\frac{ab+cd}{\sqrt{a+c}}} e^{-t^2}dt + C \enspace$ for $\enspace a+c>0$ .

Comment: @user90369 Thanks for advice. Where does $t$ come from?

Comment: The best to understand this equation is to derive the equation for x ; $t:=$ the upper limit of the right integral .